# Excel Graph Change X-Axis from date to number?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I currently have a graph in Excel that plots an accumulating data stream against dates. Instead of having dates on the x-axis, I'd like it to show the dates as just numbers from 1 to the end. For example if the axis shows: Feb, March, April, May. I'd like it to just show 1,2,3,4. Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

Comment: Add an additional helper column with the numbers and plot against that.

Answer (score 0):

As DavidPostill said, this needs the help of the auxiliary column.

On the basis of the original chart, you may right click the chart > Select Data > Edit for horizontal Axis labels, select the data range of auxiliary column.

[image]

If the data on X axis do not show right, please also make sure the settings for Axis are appropriate.

[image]